# Testing @MultipartForm RestEasy Rest Based Web Service

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

Does anyone know how to test the below @MultipartForm RestEasy Webservice? I'm unsure of how to setup the request to the below service, any ideas?

```java
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response create(@MultipartForm FileUploadForm form) {
    System.out.println("test");
    return null;
}


public class FileUploadForm {
    private byte[] filedata;

    public FileUploadForm() {}

    public byte[] getFileData() {
        return filedata;
    }

    @FormParam("filedata")
    @PartType("application/octet-stream")
    public void setFileData(final byte[] filedata) {
        this.filedata = filedata;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following blog. Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://ankiewsky.blogspot.com/2008/07/resteasy-tips-part-1.html

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a duplicate of:

[RestEasy client framework file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808246/resteasy-client-framework-file-upload/15714650)

I just posted an answer with some general guidelines on how I just got this working over there.