# JAX-RS 2.0 Client - send multipart message with RESTEasy client

Tags: java, rest, client, jax-rs, resteasy

I am using RESTEasy client.
Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And I don't know how to call on webresource using multipart?

On server side is method defined like this:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MimeHelp.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MimeHelp.JSON_UTF8)
@Path("/path")
public Response multipart(@Multipart(value = "firstPart", type = "text/plain") InputStream firstStream,
                          @Multipart(value = "secondPart", type = "text/plain") InputStream secondStream) {
```

And now please help me with client code

```
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080").path("path");
//TODO somehow fill multipart
Response response = target.request().put(/*RESTEasy multipart entity or something*/);
response.close();
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19987635) to [RestEasy client framework file upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808246) might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to "lefloh" comment - I finally done it!

You have to add these maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is the client code:

```
ResteasyClient client = (ResteasyClient) this.client;
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080").path("path");
MultipartFormDataOutput mdo = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
mdo.addFormData("firstPart", new ByteArrayInputStream("firstContent".getBytes()), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
mdo.addFormData("secondPart", new ByteArrayInputStream("secondContent".getBytes()), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
GenericEntity<MultipartFormDataOutput> entity = new GenericEntity<MultipartFormDataOutput>(mdo) { };
Response response = target.request().put(Entity.entity(entity, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE));
response.close();
```

Comment: Hello, is there any way to do this without depending on an specific implementation of JAX-RS 2.0? I need to develop a similar cliente but not tied to any of them. MultipartFormDataOutput is specific to RESTEasy. Thanks.

Comment: No, there is not. As far as I know. JAX-RS specification do not cover multipart.